# Web-based MP4 refusing to play in Safari 10.1.1 (standard setup) but does play Chrome 58 (standard setup)?

Tags: swift, macos, video, safari, avplayer

Ok, so I have noticed that somehow **Safari** (Version 10.1.1 (12603.2.4), using a standard setup with no add-on's or settings modifications) sometimes refuses to play .mp4 files that **Chrome** (Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit), also a standard setup) seems to play without a problem.

I discovered the issue since I am building a macOS Cocoa Application with Xcode that helps me browse WayBack media files. It's a hobby project to help me get more familiar with coding in Swift. Since it refused to play a lot of MP4 files I decided to try these links in Safari and noticed they failed as well. Then, trying Chrome, they all work.

My OS = macOS 10.12.5 (Sierra)

[This video](https://web.archive.org/web/20170413142652/https://vt.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_omifjgVHzi1v9ct1f.mp4) is such an example.

**Does anyone know why a basic Safari setup apparently is unable to play the mp4?**

**NB: While I know that the MP4 file from the given link (below) *does* work in Safari if I play it directly from the original source (so not retrieving it from the WayBack server) I also need to understand why it is refusing to play via the given link and how to fix that.**

Could it have something to do with the link being an HTTPS link, or might it it be a macOS issue? (As I have found that the AVPlayer of my macOS Cocoa App also refuses to play these videos).

Sorry to post such a broad question. I've searched online for similar posts to find out what the problem might be. I've found that there can be a lot of different reasons as to why browsers might or might not play videos.

A lack of in-depth knowledge prevents me from understanding how to properly troubleshoot this issue in a correct manner. It also prevented me from being able to fine-tune the question any further.

Comment: the problem seems to be the WebArchive redirect. If you remove that and just hit the video directly then it plays in Safari https://vt.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_omifjgVHzi1v9ct1f.mp4

Comment: @Offbeatmammal ah yes, forgot to mention that. I am working on an app that browses through the way back media, so I actually need to get these links working in AVplayer. But since Safari was also blocking them I figured: if I can find out why that is, I might gain insights on how to fix it in my Cocoa app as well..

Comment: So I'd still like to get that specific link working..

Comment: looking in the network tools for Safari and Chrome I see some differences in the requests, especially between the WayBack and direct, so it may be that you've found an edge case that Safari (and Apple in general) aren't handling. I'd log a Safari bug and see if that helps, but also maybe download both versions (WayBack and Tumblr) and make sure they are identical

Comment: @Offbeatmammal, thnx for the insights! I will follow the proposed steps. I did notice that WayBack has been making multiple changes to their API, so it might be they are changing their overall protocols as well. I've been working on a similar app some months ago and didn't experience the same problems then.. so yes, maybe the new setup of WayBack has caused some edge case.